# Clicking on anchor link returns NULL as offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a standard menu and JS for smooth scrolling between the anchors.
When I click on one of the anchors it do nothing but i get an error in the dev tools.

Here is my menu:

```
<div class="menu anc">
    <ul class="nav menu">
        <li class="item-111"><a href="#stills">stills</a></li>
        <li class="item-112"><a href="#art">art</a></li>
        <li class="item-113"><a href="#interactive">interactive</a></li>
        <li class="item-114"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
        <li class="item-115"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The JS part:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("header ul.menu li:first-child").addClass('active');
    $(".anc a").click(function(event){      
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amitt314/tXaLC/5/

and the error from crome dev tools:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'offset' of null script.js:18
> (anonymous function) script.js:18 x.event.dispatch jquery.js:4676
> y.handle jquery.js:4360
```

Why The anchor returns a NULL value? when i trying to remove the script everything works just fine.

Comment: I don't get errors when trying with a fiddle, but judging by the answers, that's probably just me.

Comment: I also failed to duplicate the error using the jsFiddle code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a jQuery conflict.

Probably one of the components loaded jQuery to my page and cause this conflict.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("header ul.menu li:first-child").addClass('active');
        $(".anc a").click(function(event){      
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(event.target.hash).offset().top}, 500);
        });
     });
```

Comment: Thank you.
It wors now, but without the smooth scrolling. I'll check it out.

Comment: This is your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/amitt314/tXaLC/5/   and you have not included jquery .

Comment: Remove this : $(evt.target)  from starting of code . I have updated my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** you have to include `jquery` first then try `$($(this).attr('href'))` in place of `$(this.hash)` like ,

```
 $(".anc a").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500);   
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cnbPU/)

Comment: The hash (the part of the URL including and following the hashtag) is being passed as a jQuery selector (e.g. – $('#stills')) to return a jQuery object, which he can call $.offset() on. Your code (using the .href property) is attempting to call $.offset() on a string. This will fail.

Comment: Also, your second method attempts to make a jQuery selection using a full URL (e.g. – http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#interactive) to make the selection, which will also fail.

Comment: @AmitT. try my answer once I've `changed` it.

Comment: @RohanKumar Hi, I see it works in fiddle, but in the real site this returns the same. NULL.